# How to run command on each workplace, which has changes since last commit?

Tags: git, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to run the command on workplaces, which were changed since last commit:

```
 yarn workspaces foreach --verbose --since --no-private npm info
```

My yarnrc.yml includes this setting to specify the previous commit

```
changesetBaseRefs:
  - HEAD~
```

But it still runs on all workspaces.

I tried checking changes with

```
yarn version check
```

And it shows the exact 2 packages that were changed.

Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add -R tag

```
yarn workspaces foreach --since --no-private -R npm info
```

Find packages via dependencies/devDependencies instead of using the workspaces field. Here you can read more: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/foreach#options-R%2C-recursive